# Подскажите Web Api для получения в браузере видео потока захвата экрана с удаленного компьютера?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, html5, websocket, потоки-данных

Нужен инструмент для проведения онлайн вебинаров. В моем понимании это выглядит как передача видео потока захваченного с экрана пользователя который ведет вебинар. Пользователи используя браузер подключаются к стриму после авторизации на сайте. Ведущий открывает у себя слайды, к примеру в PowerPoint. Пока что идея передавать аудио/видео поток с помощью WebRTC. Не знаю правда как провести захват экрана.

Answer (score 1):

Захват экрана средствами Web не производится.

Для проведения стрима можно использовать другие программные средства. Например: [Open BroadCaster Sofware](https://obsproject.com/) или [xSplit](https://www.xsplit.com/). Первый является полностью бесплатным OpenSource проектом, второй нет. В настройках данных программ можно указать адрес вашего медиа сервера. 
Также программы умеют очень много приятных настроек и дополнений (plugins).

Надеюсь мой ответ поможет вам разобраться в технологиях используемых для онлайн вещания с использованием захвата экрана и окон других приложений.